# OS X: How to get the current network location inside a bash function?

Tags: macos, bash, scselect, escaping

I need to use the current network location inside a bash script conditional. I've tried using the `scselect` command, which outputs an asterisk next to the current location:

```
~/ scselect 
Defined sets include: (* == current set)
   70209F72-5BE9-44D1-979E-A8BA25A317B4 (Office)
 * BDF51A74-6547-4747-BD21-30C51DA26CB1 (Automatic)
```

This doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ `scselect | grep "*.*Automatic"` ]; then
    ...
fi
```

due to the `*` in the output of `scselect` that expands into the filename list in the current directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue.

```
$ scselect | awk '{if ($1=="*") print $3}'
(Automatic)
```

If you like you can also use `sed` to strip the parens.

```
$ scselect | awk '{if ($1=="*") print $3}' | sed 's/[()]//g'
Automatic
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just escape the `*` with a `\`. Also, it looks like `scselect`, at least on Snow Leopard, outputs the defined sets to stderr instead of stdout, so you probably need to redirect stderr to stdout:

```
scselect 2>&1 | grep "\*.*Automatic"
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
if [ `scselect | grep "*.*Automatic"` ]; then
```

Means: run the scselect command, and grep for *.*Automatic which is an invalid regular expression.  The asterisk is a modifier to the previous atom ("thing") in the expression, so it can't be the first thing.

If you want to match an actual asterisk, you have to escape it with a backslash.

Spiff suggested this, but used double-quotes which will not pass the backslash on, you have to use single quotes, or a double-backslash.  Confused yet?  :)

So that would give:

```
if [ `scselect | grep '\*.*Automatic'` ]; then
```

Which means, run the scselect command, find the line that matches *.*Automatic and output it, then use that as the arguments to the 'test' command (also known as '[').

The test command does not take a line of output from scselect as an argument.

What you really mean to do is to not use the test command at all:

```
if scselect | grep '\*.*Automatic'; then
```

But as Spiff mentioned, for some silly reason, scselect sends its output to stderr not stdout.

So now you end up with:

```
if scselect 2>&1 | grep '\*.*Automatic'; then
```

Which works great, but still sends that line that grep is giving us to STDOUT, which we probably don't want in our output, so let's fix that:

```
if scselect 2>&1 | grep '\*.*Automatic' >/dev/null 2>&1; then
```

And... there you go.